# Panther sequence in Black or White by Michael Jackson

Tags: meaning, music-video, michael-jackson

Why did Michael Jackson decide to end the [*Black or White*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_or_White) music video (which otherwise talked about peace, love, fearlessness and harmony) with a black panther turning into Jackson and wrecking stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson attempted to explain the meaning of the sequence in a press release that described the four-minute sequence as an “interpretation of the panther’s wild and animalistic behavior”.

From: 
Cicerone, Michael. “Michael’s Video Takes Beating; 4 Minutes Cut Reaction: Negative Response Causes Michael Jackson to Apologize for VideoSequence in Which He Attacks a Car and Simulates Masturbation.”
Los Angeles Times
16 Nov. 1991

http://www.academia.edu/2462183/Michael_Jackson_s_Panther_Dance_Double_Consciousness_and_the_Uncanny_Business_of_Performing_While_Black